# Zookeeper exception while using hbase in cygwin

Tags: hbase, apache-zookeeper

I've been trying to run hbase on cygwin on windows and I've been having quite some trouble getting this to work properly.
The issue is that I've been having quite some trouble with getting past this error as I've been unable to find any useful help about this exception.

```
user@myself ~/apache/hbase
$ ./bin/start-hbase.sh
localhost: starting zookeeper, logging to /home/user/apache/hbase/bin/../logs/hbase-myself-zookeeper-myself.out
starting master, logging to /home/user/apache/hbase/bin/../logs/hbase-myself-master-myself.out
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/zookeeper/KeeperException
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2521)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2764)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1653)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
localhost: starting regionserver, logging to /home/user/apache/hbase/bin/../logs/hbase-myself-regionserver-myself.out
localhost: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/zookeeper/KeeperException
localhost:      at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
localhost:      at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2521)
localhost:      at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2764)
localhost:      at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1653)
localhost:      at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
localhost:      at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
localhost: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException
localhost:      at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
localhost:      at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
```

To get this running, I've been working with these websites:
http://hbase.apache.org/book/quickstart.html
http://hbase.apache.org/cygwin.html
http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh/3/hbase/cygwin.html
http://alans.se/blog/2010/hadoop-hbase-cygwin-windows-7-x64/

None of these has a solution for this problem so I have no clue about what I did wrong.

I can confirm that the zookeeper zookeeper-3.4.5.jar is in /home/user/apache/hbase/lib
I'm using hbase version 0.94.12.
I'm using cygwin version 1.7.25 x64 version.

Answer (score 0):

HBASE version = 0.94.12
CYGwin environment

Goto /hbase/conf/Hbase-env.sh

HBASE_CLASSPATH = /cygdrive/c/cygwin/usr/local/hbase-0.94.12/lib/zookeeper-3.4.5.jar

will resolve zookeeper exception...

Comment: That does not solve anything... The classpath is to include directories, not files.